# R - Image masks and lettercloud not displayed correctly

Tags: r, word-cloud, image-masking, wordcloud2

I have recently picked up R and while most of it has been a fairly straightforward process, the final step in my little script based on the `wordcloud2` package for R is proving to be difficult. I want to create word clouds - which works perfectly - but I was looking into using image masks as the shape for said word clouds, which is where I'm stuck. Similarly, if I'm using the `lettercloud` function, I have the same result.

In both cases, the image (or the letter) is displayed in its actual shape, rather than the words that should be displayed on top of them.

For clarification, I am referring to the image mask & lettercloud functions as shown here (illustrated): https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/the-wordcloud2-library/

My code for the image mask word cloud looks as follows:

```
wordcloud2(myData,
           figPath = "C:/R Projects/Word Cloud - Template/Cool/default.png", 
           size = 1.5, color = "skyblue", backgroundColor="black")
```

And for the lettercloud:

```
letterCloud(myData, word = "S", color='random-light' , backgroundColor="black")
```

I can remove all other parameters like size or color, but *they* all work, just not the shape changing.

Here is a full code snippet which should make the lettercloud reproducible. `wordcloud2` is the only required package; demoFreq is a data.frame that comes with this package:

```
library(wordcloud2)
letterCloud(demoFreq, word = "S", color='random-light' , backgroundColor="black")
```

Some additional details & things I've tried so far:

- I'm using RStudio 1.1.442 & R 3.4.4.
- I've tried reinstalling the `wordcloud2` package directly from its source using `devtools`
- I've tried viewing the output in various browsers, refreshing the image several times, but it always just shows the same wordless shape
- Tried with several data.frames, both the ones included with the `wordcloud2` package and my own

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Hi MrFlick, thanks for the heads up! I edited the comment to include a more complete code snippet which should make it possible to reproduce the problem.